# Can I use the export/import data in SQL 2008 with FK constrained tables?

Tags: sql-server-2008, export, import, sql, foreign-key

For sending data back and forth between tables having identical schema I have used the import/export task in management studio.

The problem is that SQLServer seems to do the import/export ops in whatever order it sees fit.
This causes issues with FK constrained tables that need to be imported in the specific cascading order.

I know that I can write SSIS packages to do these ops in whatever order I like, but sometimes the import/export task is just easier for ad-hoc data changes.

Is there a way I can tell SQL Server to perform the task in the proper order for the constraints?

EDIT:
I know that I can `ALTER TABLE` to disable and enable FK's... I guess I'm just wondering if there's a setting to make the import/export task do this automatically for constrained tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's a way to specify data transfer order to accommodate the constraints on your tables.  In fact, with more than 20 tables, the wizard will "optimize" for many tables and run several table transfers in parallel.